# Slow rendering on Android 9 and above

Tags: android, gpu, rendering, android-9.0-pie

My application has some fast changing data driven dashboard which shows change in data as animation.

Here is the video for more context on Android 7:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC5rMcgDHZ4

Everything was working fine until Android 9 and all of a sudden my animation became too janky and slow, note I have not made any changes to the code. 
Looking at the Android 9 release notes, it does seem that I need to change anything in my code to make it work exactly as it is working on older Android versions.

Here is the video of same dashboard on Android 9:
https://youtu.be/VrEH9vwYXSA

I ran some tests to see if I can identify the issue, the only thing by running systrace and some other tests I could identify that the render thread is too busy and main thread is consistently waiting for render thread to finish its work. But other than that I have got no idea regarding why render thread is taking too much of time to issue commands to GPU.

And here is the output of 
 adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo  for both Android 9 and below 9

**Android 9**

```
Stats since: 9198579974261ns
Total frames rendered: 552
Janky frames: 550 (99.64%)
50th percentile: 65ms
90th percentile: 1000ms
95th percentile: 1650ms
99th percentile: 4000ms
Number Missed Vsync: 292
Number High input latency: 174
Number Slow UI thread: 328
Number Slow bitmap uploads: 40
Number Slow issue draw commands: 357
Number Frame deadline missed: 378
```

**Android 7**

```
Stats since: 23794947145ns
Total frames rendered: 123411
Janky frames: 121486 (98.44%)
50th percentile: 20ms
90th percentile: 25ms
95th percentile: 31ms
99th percentile: 53ms
Number Missed Vsync: 2179
Number High input latency: 0
Number Slow UI thread: 14705
Number Slow bitmap uploads: 841
Number Slow issue draw commands: 113417
```

If you see the difference between number of frames drawn between two versions is staggering.

And here is the link to systrace on Android 9
https://github.com/kapilsukhyani/car_connect/blob/master/mynewtrace.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, have you found any information about this? I have the similar problem, my janky frames is 100%

Comment: Sorry but no, I did some other optimization to make my rendering a little faster but no clue why is that behaving that way.